# Exchange Time for Memory in Python

Tags: python, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

Challenge here is in evaluating multiple large files.

What coding will instruct Python to "load" a limited number of files into memory, process them, garbage collect and then load the next set?

```
def main(directory):
    """
    Create AudioAnalysis Objects from directory and call object_analysis().
"""   
    ff = os.listdir(directory)
    for f in ff:
        # can we limit the number we load at one time?
        audiofile = audio.LocalAudioFile(os.path.join(directory,f)) # hungry!
```

Tried adding `audiofile = 0` to the loop, but the memory allocation is the same.

As I understand it, `Lazy Evaluation` "is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed", but in this case I need to *delay evaluation until there's memory available*.

Am expecting that a `decorator`, `descriptor` and/or use of Pythons `property()` function may be involved, or possibly buffering or queueing the input.

Comment: Does `LocalAudioFile` load the file into memory? It looks like your code only keeps one file--the current one--in memory at a time, loading a new file each time through the loop.

Comment: Have you tried triggering `gc.collect` in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Also what machine are you using, i.e. 32 or 64 bit? What OS as well? Could be that others can manage it they way it is. I still hail being curious but just to help you with the problem of running out of memory, which I assume you have.

Comment: Well my dev OS is osx 64 bit (`sysctl hw.cpu64bit_capable returns 1`), but I'm hoping the solution will be portable - planning to host `*NIX`, maybe with Linode. And am way past memory limits on a 1GB plan.

Comment: @tobias_k tried gc.collect yesterday (and again just now) and it doesn't seem to effect the memory grab happening a the loop.

Comment: @chepner `LocalAudioFile` certainly seems to load file into memory as well as creating an object associated with it. The memory usage their increases concurrently with number of files, so it must be loading them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution: have Python spawn a process, run the function on one file, then exit. The parent proc will collect results from each of the files.

This is in no way graceful, but if `LocalAudioFile` refuses to be dislodged from memory, it allows some flexibility in getting results.

This code runs runs a function on each Python file in the current directory, returning a message to the parent process, which prints it out.

### source

```
import glob, multiprocessing, os

def proc(path):
    """
    Create AudioAnalysis Objects from directory and call object_analysis().
"""   
    # audiofile = audio.LocalAudioFile(path) # hungry!
    return 'woot: {}'.format(path)

if __name__=='__main__':  # required for Windows
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()   # one Process per CPU
    for output in pool.map(proc, [
            os.path.abspath(name) for name in glob.glob('q*.py')
            ]):
        print 'output:',output
```

### output

```
output: woot: /home/johnm/src/johntellsall/karma/qpopen.py
output: woot: /home/johnm/src/johntellsall/karma/quotes.py
```

Comment: Going now to look up the multiprocessing module, but should I be able to substitute `glob.glob('*.mp3')` for `glob.glob('q*.py')` here or am i misunderstanding the solution?

Comment: @MikeiLL yes, `glob.glob('*.mp3')` is fine. Have fun!

Comment: This is really interesting. `KeyboardInterrupt` isn't `stopping` the process. I guess because it just stops a single call to process. Using osX Activity Monitor to achieve that.

Comment: signals and multiprocessing really don't like each other

Comment: And tips on how I might go about profiling? Getting error when trying to add the `@profile` decorator I was using earlier" `cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

Comment: Get a serial version to work, that handles a single audio (small) audio file. Then extend it to handle multiple files, or a single large file.  With progress things will become more clear.